# AngularJS - input number spinner, not working correctly when number is inputted manually

Tags: angularjs, directive

here on stackoverflow I found a directive made by an user for angularJS, for a input number spinner, and I was just looking for it!

All working good, but one thing is not, when you manually enter a number in the input field, and press MINUS, it s gonna subtract 1 from that number, all good here,

but when you input a number and as first thing you press PLUS, instead of adding 1, it's gonna add a `"1"` next to the number you wrote!
Only going "minus" once fixes it,

can someone help me fix the code to avoid this? I want that when I put the number manually, you can press on "plus" and get `+1` on that number!

http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/84qxvgm8/

Comment: not quite _adding_ `1`, but concatenating it. E.g `1+1` gives `2`, whereas `"1"+1` gives `"11"`. Minus doesn't have that property, so `"11"-1` gives `10`. A hack / quick fix for it is to cast a Number: `scope.ngModel = Number(scope.ngModel) + 1;`

Comment: you are always on point @AlekseySolovey ! That worked like a charm! thank you very much, write it down as answerand I ll mark it as the one!

Comment: can I ask you one more thing, I was trying to edit the code to only accept POSITIVE numbers, I tried using this regex: '/^\d*[1-9]\d*$/' but what happens in that if I press the minus while 0 is displayed, it s gonna return an empty input field, and I can't anymore use "plus" or "minus" until I manually insert a new positive number, can you help me with this?

Comment: honestly, the code is a mess, `ng-pattern` deletes the value if it doesn't fit the regex expression, leaving it as `undefined`. Casting `Number()` only partially solves the issue. You can type such values as `1.2.3`, which bypasses the pattern as a valid number, but after casting a Number on it or doing `+1` or `-1` operations, the result is obviously `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`input type="text"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) will return a string as a model value,  and as was mentioned by @AlekseySolovey - you'll have to cast it to a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (since `"10" + 1` will give you "101" as a result). As you are using `numericOnly` directive as well, it seems to be the right place to do the conversion, since you'll wave to do it only in the one place. Here is an example:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular
        .module("app", []);

    app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.testNumber = 10;
    }]);

    app.directive('numericOnly', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                    if (angular.isNumber(inputValue)) {
                        return inputValue;
                    }

                    var transformedInput = inputValue ? Number(inputValue.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '')) : null;

                    if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                        modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        modelCtrl.$render();
                    }

                    return transformedInput;
                });
            }
        };
    });

    app.directive('numberSpin', [function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                "ngModel": '='
            },
            template: '<div>' +
            '<input numeric-only data-ng-model="ngModel" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" type="text">' +
            '<a class="ns-plus"  data-ng-click="plus()">+</a>' +
            '<a class="ns-minus"data-ng-click="minus()">-</a> </div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;

                scope.plus = function () {
                    scope.ngModel = scope.ngModel + 1;
                };

                scope.minus = function () {
                    scope.ngModel = scope.ngModel - 1;
                };

            }
        }

    }])


}());
```

```css
number-spin div {
  position: relative;
  width: 126px;
  
}
number-spin input {
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

number-spin .ns-plus {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 16px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 16px;
}

number-spin .ns-minus {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" style="padding: 16px; "data-ng-controller="AppController as vm">


<number-spin data-ng-model="vm.testNumber"></number-spin>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:** A bit simpler code that allows passing `min`/`max` into the directive:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular
        .module("app", []);

    app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.testNumber = 10;
    }]);

    app.directive('numberSpin', [function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                "ngModel": '=',
                "min": '<',
                "max": '<',
                "step": '<'
            },
            template: '<div>' +
            '<input data-ng-model="ngModel" type="number" ng-attr-min="{{min}}" ng-attr-max="{{max}}">' +
            '<a class="btn ns-plus" data-ng-click="plus()">+</a>' +
            '<a class="btn ns-minus"data-ng-click="minus()">-</a> </div>',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                scope.plus = function () {
                    if (scope.ngModel >= scope.max) return;
                    scope.ngModel += (scope.step || 1);
                    checkModel()
                };

                scope.minus = function () {
                    if (scope.ngModel <= scope.min) return;
                    scope.ngModel -= (scope.step || 1);
                    checkModel();
                };

                function checkModel() {
                    if (!scope.ngModel) scope.ngModel = scope.min || 0;
                }

            }
        }

    }])


}());
```

```css
number-spin div {
    position: relative;
    width: 126px;

}

number-spin input {
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

number-spin .btn {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

number-spin .ns-plus {
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

number-spin .ns-minus {
    bottom: 0;
}

number-spin input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
number-spin input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" style="padding: 16px; "data-ng-controller="AppController as vm">


<number-spin data-ng-model="vm.testNumber" min="0" max="15"></number-spin>

</div>
```

Comment: can I ask you one more thing, I was trying to edit the code to only accept POSITIVE numbers, I tried using this regex: '/^\d*[1-9]\d*$/' but what happens in that if I press the minus while 0 is displayed, it s gonna return an empty input field, and I can't anymore use "plus" or "minus" until I manually insert a new positive number, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("app", ['tien.stepInput']);

    app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
       
       $scope.demo = 10
       $scope.options = {
          min_value: 1,
          overrides: [
              {value: 1, style: 'danger', view_value: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'},
              {value: 0, style: 'warning', view_value: '<i class="fa fa-question"></i>'}
          ]
      };
       
    });

}());
```

```css
.tien-step {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 93px; }
  .tien-step button, .tien-step .step-value {
    border: none;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center; }
    .tien-step button:focus, .tien-step button:active, .tien-step button:focus:active, .tien-step .step-value:focus, .tien-step .step-value:active, .tien-step .step-value:focus:active {
      outline: none; }
  .tien-step button {
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 24px; }
  .tien-step .step-value {
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-heigth: 22px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 45px; }
  .tien-step.primary button {
    background: #428bca; }
    .tien-step.primary button:active {
      background: #3071a9; }
    .tien-step.primary button.disabled {
      opacity: 0.8; }
      .tien-step.primary button.disabled:active {
        background: #428bca; }
  .tien-step.primary .step-value {
    border-color: #428bca; }
    .tien-step.primary .step-value i.fa {
      color: #428bca;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      top: -2px;
      position: relative; }
  .tien-step.success button {
    background: #5cb85c; }
    .tien-step.success button:active {
      background: #449d44; }
    .tien-step.success button.disabled {
      opacity: 0.8; }
      .tien-step.success button.disabled:active {
        background: #5cb85c; }
  .tien-step.success .step-value {
    border-color: #5cb85c; }
    .tien-step.success .step-value i.fa {
      color: #5cb85c;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      top: -2px;
      position: relative; }
  .tien-step.info button {
    background: #5bc0de; }
    .tien-step.info button:active {
      background: #31b0d5; }
    .tien-step.info button.disabled {
      opacity: 0.8; }
      .tien-step.info button.disabled:active {
        background: #5bc0de; }
  .tien-step.info .step-value {
    border-color: #5bc0de; }
    .tien-step.info .step-value i.fa {
      color: #5bc0de;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      top: -2px;
      position: relative; }
  .tien-step.warning button {
    background: #f0ad4e; }
    .tien-step.warning button:active {
      background: #ec971f; }
    .tien-step.warning button.disabled {
      opacity: 0.8; }
      .tien-step.warning button.disabled:active {
        background: #f0ad4e; }
  .tien-step.warning .step-value {
    border-color: #f0ad4e; }
    .tien-step.warning .step-value i.fa {
      color: #f0ad4e;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      top: -2px;
      position: relative; }
  .tien-step.danger button {
    background: #d9534f; }
    .tien-step.danger button:active {
      background: #c9302c; }
    .tien-step.danger button.disabled {
      opacity: 0.8; }
      .tien-step.danger button.disabled:active {
        background: #d9534f; }
  .tien-step.danger .step-value {
    border-color: #d9534f; }
    .tien-step.danger .step-value i.fa {
      color: #d9534f;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      top: -2px;
      position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-step-input.10kb.nl/angular-step-input.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <tien-step-input ng-model="demo"></tien-input-step>
</div>
```